# Inspect HTML at specific keyframe

Tags: html, debugging, browser

I have a website that has react animation on enter. Before it is fully loaded some stuff is happening for slight second. How can I inspect html before the animation ends and website fully loads? I am aware of animations tab but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I need to see entire html that generates right at beginning before any changes. I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect animations at specific keyframes :)
I'm not 100% sure that this is what you need, but here's an article related to your question, hope this helps...
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/animations/#modify

Comment: It is not picking the first animation maybe because nothing visually changes.  But the problem happens at beginning when div has class "enter enter-active" and disappears when it changes to "enter done". Still that won't help because I need to inspect entire html when it is still in active state not just the animation.